# Does Jest support dependent tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Is it possible to only run a test in Jest if a previous test has passed? I can't find anything in the documentation about a truthy callback. For example:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

describe("Test task", () => {
  test("array length", () => {
    expect(array).toHaveLength(4);;
  });
  test("first item value", () => {
    expect(array[0]).toBe(1);;
  });
});
```

Trivial example, but would it be possible for the "first item value" test to only run if the "array length" test has passed, **without** just doing the following

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

describe("Test task", () => {
  test("array length", () => {
    expect(array).toHaveLength(4);;
  });
  if(array.length == 4){
    test("first item value", () => {
      expect(array[0]).toBe(1);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Haven't fiddled with Jest but can't you just nest the `test`s?

Comment: Thanks @NicholasKyriakides you're right, don't know why I didn't consider that.

Comment: If it works post it as an answer and self-accept it so the question goes out of the unanswered queue.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work actually. I get the error "Tests cannot be nested. Test `child test name` cannot run because it is nested within `parent test name`." I'm going to with the if statement approach for now, and dig a little deeper further down the line. Deadlines take precedence unfortunately.

Comment: What's your end goal? Speed up test running, simplify debugging, or something else? The best solution will depend on why you want to do this.

Comment: Readability and less repeated code.

Comment: Mocha has something like this, they call it steps https://github.com/rprieto/mocha-steps There is a runner implementation for jest and mocha but unfortunately it seems they stopped working https://github.com/rogeliog/jest-runner-mocha

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly wacky way of doing this:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3]

describe("Test task", () => {
  const conditionalTest = bool => (bool ? test : test.skip)

  test("array length", () => {
    expect(array).toHaveLength(4)
  })

  conditionalTest(array.length === 4)("first item value", () => {
    expect(array[0]).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

As you can see, the function/method "test" is dependent on a truthy value you give it, so if the condition equates to false, it uses the "test.skip" function built into Jest, thus ignoring the test. If its true, it just uses the normal "test" method.

It is not the prettiest, but it works until Jest someday makes their own version of this functionality.